# Ways to run loop across 2 lists

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am trying to run a loop across 2 lists which are as follows -

```
list_a = [227, 316, 384, 475, 564, 660, 781, 882, 968, 1156, 1216, 1304]
list_b = [313, 380, 470, 561, 650, 778, 878, 964, 1152, 1212, 1301, 1346]
```

I am trying to run a for loop with list_b value as end value and list_a values as starting value. Here is the code I have -

```
for a in range(0, len(list_b)):
  for i in range(list_a[a], list_b[a]):
    *do_something*
```

Is there any other better way I can do this?

Comment: Use `zip()` to loop over the two lists in parallel.

Comment: `for start, end in zip(list_a, list_b):`

Comment: Thats not what OP asked for. Please open this question again.

Comment: `for i in (i for s, e in zip(a, b) for i in range(s, e)):  ...`

Comment: what precisely is the behavior your need? Can you please add an example with two small lists?